# How to get credit card details of Paypal Recurring payments profile

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am creating a Recurring payment profile using Direct payment(credit card details entered during registration are not stored in database). I want to update/change the bill amount for every bill cycle(because billing is done per user per month).

I am using UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails API method to change the amount, but the method needs credit card details again(for each time it is called). I am getting the credit card details using GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails, but this method just returns the last 4 digits of credit card(and does not return CVV2, but this is not major issue here).

Is there any other option to get the full credit card details(at least credit card number) using Paypal APIs or should I have to store credit card numbers in my database? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For the `UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` API method, you shouldn't need the credit card details to update the user's profile. You should only need the `PROFILEID` generated by PayPal upon a successful `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` method.

Comment: @Chase: thank you very much. all we need is PROFILEID. In the API documentation, all possible request fields are listed. I had mistaken them for mandatory fields. So got confused. After seeing your comment, I called UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails with just Amount field and PROFILEID and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unlikely that you'll be able to get the full credit card number from PayPal; that's why people use PayPal.

Storing credit card information in your database is a huge liability, and should be avoided if at all possible. Once you start storing that information, your company is responsible for keeping that information secure (and that includes developers). Use another third party component if you must, but don't take on such an enormous liability.

I don't know what company you work for, but that's not a decision that a developer should be making on their own. Entire companies have been shut down for mishandling credit card information. The law around that stuff is extremely murky, and even the smallest mistake can result in massive fines.

Comment: thanks for the info. my job can be done with out storing the credit card details. i was confused by the API documentation.